# Send the data from java to the Jasper Tables

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

My problem it's that I Have to do a report who have 2 tables inside. Tables who I must fill sending its data using java, like using a JavaBean Connection.

Example. I have 3 class

```
class MainFields{
int id; String name; String code;
/*Getters and Setters*/}

class SubTable1{
int materialCode; String materialName; String materialLocation;
/*Getters and Setters*/}

class SubTable2{
int serviceCode; String serviceName; float cost;
/*Getters and Setters*/}
```

I know that using

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
"Absolute Path of the jasper");
JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
report, hashMapOfParameter, CollectionBeans);
```

being

- **report**: a object tipe JasperReport
- **hashMapOfParameter**: a HashMap with the parameters I send to the jasper
- **CollectionBeans**: a Vector with the diferent fields of the main query

I wanna send 2 more Vectors to fill 2 tables in the report.

```
Vector<SubTable1> vst1;
Vector<SubTable2> vst2;
```

Actually I'm using iReport.

I don't know if really I can do that Using Jasper + Java but I see that I can use JavaBeans as datasource in iReport and I wanna know if It's true.